# C#のDllImportに関して

Tags: c#

こんにちは、お世話になります。

C#のDllImportで明示的にカレントディレクトリのDLLをインポートさせたいんですが、下記のソースだとコンパイルエラーになってしまうようです。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class main{
string curdir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
[DllImport(curdir+"\\test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
extern static int test(int num);
（後略）
```

コンパイルエラーは、下記です。  
    test.cs(7,16): error CS0120: 静的でないフィールド、メソッド、またはプロパティ 'main.curdir' で、オブジェクト参照が必要です

なにか明示的にカレントディレクトリのDLLを読み込むようにする方法はありますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事に出ています。
[DllImportで実行時にdllを指定するには？](https://qiita.com/Temarin/items/8ddcf6bc8e793f834427)

> 結論
>   DllImportでdllを読み込む前にLoadLibrary関数でDLLを読み込んでおくことで同名のdllは、今後、読み込み済みのDLLを参照するようになる。

上記対処を行えば、以下のパス指定は無くしてファイル名だけで良くなるのでは？

```
[DllImport(curdir+"\\test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

---

## 追記

検索し直したら、こんな記事が見つかりました。
こちらの方がソースコードがすっきりするでしょう。
[DLLの読み込み。DLLを探す検索パスの順序を変更する。...](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tekk/20090824/1251122412)

アプリケーション構成ファイル（application名.exe.config）またはDLL/COMリダイレクションファイル（application名.exe.local）で指定するようです。

関連するMicrosoftの記事はこれです。
 [Element<プローブ>要素](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element)
[DLL/COM リダイレクション](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms811700.aspx#sidebyside_topic8)

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えていただいたサイトをもとに、「string dllPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "test.dll");」というコードを記述したのですが、コンパイル時に「名前 'Path' は現在のコンテキスト内に存在しません。」というエラーが表示されてしまいます。何か対処法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: using System.IO;を追加してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみましたが、DllImportをinternal classに入れたからなのか、今度はDLLの関数を呼ぶところで、「名前 'test' は現在のコンテキスト内に存在しません。」というコンパイルエラーが出てしまいます。何か対処法はありますでしょうか。質問ばかりで申し訳ないのですが、教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 紹介Link先にあるように、DllImport定義の中に EntryPoint = "test", CallingConvention = test()の呼び出し形式, を加えれば良いのでは？ test()がnamespace付きで作られている場合は、EntryPointでそれも含めて指定する必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: 指定してみましたが、ダメなようです。もうちょっと調べてみますが。